# Is there an easy way to update all certificates on a non-networked Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, certificate

I have a Windows 7 PC that is not permitted to connected to the internet, as it contains some sensitive data. Due to the lack of connection, it isn't receiving any Windows updates either.

I am getting more and more problems installing newer software onto this PC, because many installation packages try to verify their own integrity before installing, and this PC apparently lacks current root certificates to do so.

So is there a simple way to bring all Windows 7 certificates up to date without connecting the PC to the Internet? Ideally, I would want a small setup package just containing all current certificates. So that after running it, I would instantly have the same set of root certificates as on a PC connected to the Internet receiving all needed updates. Is there such a thing? I looked at the Microsoft site, but all I found was a long text for network administrators about managing certificates on an internal network. But I don't want to "manage" anything, I just want to have all certificates exactly like they would be on a networked PC.

Alternatively, is there a way to just copy all root certificates from a PC connected to the Internet without exporting and importing each certificate per hand?

Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Updates can be downloaded from the Windows Update Catalog, saved to a disk, and then manually installed on offline computers. This should take care of most of your problems.

Comment: The simplest way would be installed the associated updates that install the required certificates.  You can also export the certificates from a machine that is connected to the internet.  The best solution entirely depends on what you are allowed to change.  If you are not authorized for either of these suggestions, find somebody who is, and ask them how to proceed.

Comment: Also, there are a couple utilities from MS that can handle this. See if this document helps: http://woshub.com/updating-trusted-root-certificates-in-windows-10/